# radius of convergence proof confusion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Definition of radius of convergence: $R=\sup\{|z| \in \mathbb R :\sum|c_kz^k|\,\text{converges}\}$.

Prove that if $|z|<R$ then $\sum|c_kz^k|$ converges and if $|z|>R$ then the sum diverges.

What is there to prove, isn't everything just from the definition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not trivial that if $0<s<r$ and $\sum_k|c_kr^k|$ converges then $\sum_k|c_ks^k|$ converges.

Comment: Look up the proof of the Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ahh I see now, this statement isn't trivial at all, thank you!

Comment: There is a nice simple proof of the C-H formula  in Complex Calculus, by Ahlfors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose we look at the reals. What if we know that the set of $z$ where the sum converges contains the rationals between $0$ and $1$, and no number larger than $1$ (but may contain other numbers as well). Then $R = 1$, by the definition, but do we know the series converges at $\sqrt{2}/2$, for instance? Why?

You might also ask yourself "why isn't $|z| = R$ included in either of the two sets I'm supposed to prove something about?

Comment: Ah I see, the second statement isn't trivial at all, wouldn't the first statement about $|z|<R$ be true automatically though, just by definition?

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around. The second one is trivial; the first requires work (although not much).